# pass parameter to controller from route in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

How can I pass parameter to a controller from a route in laravel?

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/{slug}','SampleController@showCms');
```

This is my controller function:

```
public function showCms($slug){}
```

I want to route '/' also from this slug:

```
route(Route::get('/{slug}','SampleController@showCms'))
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What is `route(Route::get('/{slug}','SampleController@showCms'))` supposed to be? Both routes are the same, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Route::get('/{slug}','SampleController@showCms') this olny i am trying public function showCms($slug){} is controller function.I want this function also for Route('/','SampleController@showCms') this route also.

Comment: Ok, but what do you want to do? What is the problem? Is your solution not working as expected? I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: Exactly, i don't see any problem. Just pass /{some-data} and return $slug from your controller. It should work

Comment: but the url is http://localhost/website/public.it produce error.but http://localhost/website/public/{some-thing} is work.

Comment: You mean you want to also handle a route with no slug? Then just add it: `Route::get('/', function() { return 'index page'; });` Please be more specific if you're expecting people to help you, don't make them have to guess what your problem is. Explain clearly what you want to do and show the errors you are getting.

Comment: And neither .../public.it nor .../public{some-thing} are valid URLs / routes. It's either ...public/ or ...public/{slug}. The first one is handled by `Route::get('/', ...)`, the other one is handled by `Route::get('{slug}', ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
Route::get('{slug?}','SampleController@showCms');
```

Both

```
http://site.dev/
```

and

```
http://site.dev/this-is-my-slug
```

Will cause a hit on your controller

```
public function showCms($slug = null)
{
     if ($slug)
     {
         /// you got a slug here
     }
}
```